# How to add my own nginx event handler?

Tags: nginx, epoll

I'm writing a module to provide a method to process arp date.

I want to use nginx's basic structure and event module, so I write a module like the **http{}**

My problem is, I don't know how to add my read event to nginx's event loop, I try to call **ngx_add_event** in my ngx_module_t's **init_process** function, but i get a NULL ptr...

What should i do?